# Android Camera: Attempt to invoke virtual method Android Camera Parameters on android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera, android-camera2

I used my `Fabric`-service and found this error on most of the devices that are running my app.

Error was this:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters
>   android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference

**Here's my code:**

```
 public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    android.hardware.Camera camera;
    int moi = 0;
    @InjectView(R.id.s)
    SurfaceView surfaceView;

    @InjectView(R.id.takeaphoto)
    ImageView imageView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Camera.Face[] mFaces;





    // Draw rectangles and other fancy stuff:
    private FaceOverlayView mFaceView;
    private int mOrientation;
    private float x1,x2;
    static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
    private int mOrientationCompensation;
    private OrientationEventListener mOrientationEventListener;

    // Let's keep track of the display rotation and orientation also:
    private int mDisplayRotation;
    private int mDisplayOrientation;


    Camera.PictureCallback callback;
    int cameraId = 0;
    Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback;

    private Camera.FaceDetectionListener faceDetectionListener = new Camera.FaceDetectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
            Log.d("onFaceDetection", "Number of Faces:" + faces.length);
            // Update the view now!
            mFaceView.setFaces(faces);
        }

    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        Fabric.with(this, new Answers());
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_activity);

        mFaceView = new FaceOverlayView(this);
        addContentView(mFaceView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        // Create and Start the OrientationListener:
        mOrientationEventListener = new SimpleOrientationEventListener(this);
        mOrientationEventListener.enable();


        SharedPreferences pap = this.getSharedPreferences(
                "AD1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean frr = pap.getBoolean("fr", false);

        if (!frr) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Tip");
            builder.setMessage("Use the beautiful filters by swiping from right to left")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            SharedPreferences e = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                                    "AD1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor d = e.edit();
                            d.putBoolean("fr", true);
                            d.commit();

                        }

                    });


            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();


        } else {


        }



        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        surfaceHolder=surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
cameraImage();
            }
        });
        callback = new android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outputStream=null;
                File file_image = getDirc();

                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmms");
                String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
                String photo_file="PI_"+date+".jpg";
                String file_name = file_image.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+photo_file;
                File picfile=new File(file_name);

                try {

                    outputStream=new FileOutputStream(picfile);
                    outputStream.write(bytes);
                    outputStream.close();


                }catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
                catch (IOException ex){}
                finally {

                }
                refreshCamera();
                refreshGallery(picfile);

                try {
                    camera.stopPreview();
                }catch (Exception e){}

                try{

                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                    camera.startPreview();
                }catch (Exception e){}


            }


        };


        }








    private void refreshGallery(File file){
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));



    }

    public void refreshCamera(){

        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null){

            return;

        }

    }


    private class SimpleOrientationEventListener extends OrientationEventListener {

        public SimpleOrientationEventListener(Context context) {
            super(context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int i) {
            // We keep the last known orientation. So if the user first orient
            // the camera then point the camera to floor or sky, we still have
            // the correct orientation.
            if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
            mOrientation = Util.roundOrientation(orientation, mOrientation);
            // When the screen is unlocked, display rotation may change. Always
            // calculate the up-to-date orientationCompensation.
            int orientationCompensation = mOrientation
                    + Util.getDisplayRotation(CameraActivity.this);
            if (mOrientationCompensation != orientationCompensation) {
                mOrientationCompensation = orientationCompensation;
                mFaceView.setOrientation(mOrientationCompensation);
            }
        }

    }


        private File getDirc(){

File dics = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        return new File(dics ,"Camera");

    }

    public void cameraImage(){

        camera.takePicture(null , null ,callback);
       MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this , R.raw.sound);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder ) {



try {
    camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
}catch (RuntimeException ex){}
        android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        camera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
        camera.startFaceDetection();
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
        List<Camera.Size> customSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size customSize = customSizes.get(0); //Added size
        parameters.setPreviewSize(customSize.width, customSize.height);
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);


        try {

            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();


        }catch (Exception e){



        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        refreshCamera();
        setDisplayOrientation();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera=null;

    }

    public void frontCamera(View view) {

        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera=null;

        if (cameraId == 0){


            try {
                camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(1);
            }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
            camera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
            camera.startFaceDetection();
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
            List<Camera.Size> customSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();


            Camera.Size customSize = customSizes.get(0); //Added size
            parameters.setPreviewSize(customSize.width, customSize.height);
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

            cameraId = 1;


            try {

                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();


            }catch (Exception e){



            }
        }

        else{

            try {
                camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
            }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
            camera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
            camera.startFaceDetection();
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
            List<Camera.Size> customSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();


            Camera.Size customSize = customSizes.get(0); //Added size
            parameters.setPreviewSize(customSize.width, customSize.height);
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

            cameraId = 0;

            try {

                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();


            }catch (Exception e){



            }

        }
        }

    private void setDisplayOrientation() {
        // Now set the display orientation:
        mDisplayRotation = Util.getDisplayRotation(CameraActivity.this);
        mDisplayOrientation = Util.getDisplayOrientation(mDisplayRotation, 0);

        camera.setDisplayOrientation(mDisplayOrientation);

        if (mFaceView != null) {
            mFaceView.setDisplayOrientation(mDisplayOrientation);
        }
    }
```

**Here's my manifest:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.camera">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/pc"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         >
         </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="e7ded6b46068e619fd1d96f6b9eeaac888fe83f5" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `try {
    camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
}catch (RuntimeException ex){}
        parameters = camera.getParameters();` seriously ? ... if `open()` fails then obviously `camera` would be null

Answer (score 16):

Check the app in your device `Settings`, if the required permissions are given or not. In my case, this was the reason for `Exception`, that I had not given permissions from the `Settings`.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem. Your `camera` object is instantiated only if there is no `RuntimeException`. So, if this exception happens, `camera == null;`.

```
try {
    camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
}catch (RuntimeException ex){}
// Here is your problem. Catching RuntimeException will make camera object null,
// so method 'getParameters();' won't work :)
        android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        camera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
        camera.startFaceDetection();
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
        List<Camera.Size> customSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size customSize = customSizes.get(0); //Added size
        parameters.setPreviewSize(customSize.width, customSize.height);
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);


        try {

            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();


        }catch (Exception e){



        }

    }
```

Comment: That is true, I didn't notice thzt earlier, but it still gets the same error after removing the `try()` and `catch`;

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
        camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
    }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
   
if(camera != null){
            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            camera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
            camera.startFaceDetection();
            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
            List<Camera.Size> customSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Camera.Size customSize = customSizes.get(0); //Added size
            parameters.setPreviewSize(customSize.width, customSize.height);
                    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
}

    try {

        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();


    }catch (Exception e){



    }

}
```

After initializing the camera you can put a simple if condition where you can check if(camera != null){ // the code for parameter}